# CSS in LWC - lightning-combobox box to be curved (border-radius)

Tags: lightning-web-components, css, html, lightning-design-system, lightning-combobox

I want the `lightning-combobox` input box to be curved(border-radius: 18px).

**My research and attempts:**

I tried **CSS** for `lightning-input` as:

```
.slds-modal input[type="text"]{
    border-radius: 18px !important;
 }
```

and I was able to achieve this:

[image: The input box where the field is curved]

Similarily, I want the input box for `lightning-combobox` to be curved.
I implemented css for classes - `.slds-combobox__form-element`, `.slds-combobox` but no luck.

Answer (score 4):

Use the SLDS styling hook to override the border-radius. Add this code into the .css file of the component.

```
:host{
    --sds-c-input-radius-border: 18px;
}
```

The above code will be effective for all the nested components inside the current component, so if you want this only for specific components then you can add specific selectors for that.

**CSS:**

```
.my-cystom-input{
    --sds-c-input-radius-border: 18px;
}
```

**HTML:**

```
<lightning-combobox 
    name="progress" 
    label="Status" 
    value={value} 
    class="my-cystom-input"
    placeholder="Select Progress">
</lightning-combobox>
```

If you want to know more about Styling hooks then you can check out my blog posts on that.

[SLDS Styling hooks in Lightning web components](https://www.forcetrails.com/2020/10/slds-styling-hooks-in-lightning-web-components.html)

[Customize standard LWC components' with SLDS Styling Hooks](https://www.forcetrails.com/2022/01/customize-standard-lwc-components-styles-with-styling-hooks.html)